# WiFi connection does not work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking

I am sure my WiFi router is working fine because all other devices connected to the same router are working completely fine and only my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 isn't working. I get the IP address but I am not able to ping to google DNS 8.8.8.8, Network manager always shows that WiFi was last used today.I have already tried a lot of recommendations and I am not sure how to diagnose this issue. I have ran the script given by Ubuntu forum for the wifi issues and following is the link of its output.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24525652/

Comment: Are your other devices on the network that work fine also configured to use   `Current Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)`

Comment: @ElderGeek : Yes, other devices are also on 5Ghz band. Including my Mobile and one other laptop

Comment: Any help guys .. I am still without WiFi :-(

Comment: Could you please tell us what wifi drivers you currently have. You can do this by  executing this command in shell  `lscpi | grep Wireless`

Comment: Following is my driver : 02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev ff)

Comment: There's a stack trace involving `rtlwifi` in the wireless diagnostics log. Could you please [edit] your question to include the full error message and stack trace around 40 after since boot. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try reinstalling your drivers by going to this site https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new and cloning its repository. Then you can build it by typing 
 `make`
`sudo make install`
Make sure you are in the cloned repository when you perform make.

Last resort if the above fix does not work. Try downgrading or using an older kernel. This has fixed my issues in the past.

Comment: Normally realtek drivers work fine.
Try ndiswrapper. It's not powerfull but it works

Comment: Alright good information!!!

Comment: OK I move my comment as a reply

Comment: I tried re-installing the drivers with the github code, but still it does not work. Real Problem is when I get connected to WiFi, in Network settings it always shows disconnected, when I try to connect it never really switches to connected state in the Network settings, however on main screen Icon shows connected status and I can also see which wifi I am connected to.

Comment: Finally I am able to resolve this issue. I had to update the kernel and then reinstall the drivers with steps suggested above. Now wifi works without any random disconnects.

Comment: @AdityaKurude so glad I could help